# Use of ImageViewer with GUI builder codenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to build an application wich navigates via 6 multibuttons to 6 different screens in which i want to show images using the Image viewer. I am trying this with the GUI builder but it still doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

For now im trying to load the ImageViewer before loading the second form like this:

```
protected void beforeDamesEnkel(Form f) {
        ImageViewer imv = new ImageViewer();
        imv.setImage(fetchResourceFile().getImage("images.jpg"));
        imv.setSwipePlaceholder(Image.createImage(5, 5));
        f.addComponent(imv);
     }
```

Thanks in advance,
Allard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear what isn't working for you but I'm guessing it would work if you do something like:

```
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, imv);
```

Comment: Great, worked very well. I wanted the ImageViewer to show in a form after the main form but it didn't. Can you explain why i didn't? Because i had the Layout already set in the GUI builder.

Comment: Set to what? If it was set to border layout then you need to add to the center (you should have gotten an exception in the console). If it was set to something else the size might have been miscalculated.

Comment: Ok, i get it. It was a border layout indeed but didn't set it to center.